# Spring ReactiveCrudRepository ExistsQuery method returns null

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Any idea why the following code would return a mono of null? I realize why the contract would allow it but I would expect the Spring code to return either a true or a false.

```
public interface SampleRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Sample, String> {
    @ExistsQuery("{ userId: ?0 }")
    Mono<Boolean> existsWithUserId(String userId);

    @Query("{ userId: ?0 }")
    Mono<Sample> findWithUserId(String userId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this was a bug in a previous version. With Spring Boot 2.0.5 (Spring 5.0.9, Spring Data 2.0.10) and the reactive mongo driver 3.8.2 it works fine for me - null is never returned.

Please note that I explicitly use the newer mongo-driver-async 3.8.2 instead of the current default version since in the latter another bug is contained that is fixed in the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

You can change `Mono<Boolean>` to `boolean` and it will return only true or false

```
public interface SampleRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<Sample, String> {
    @ExistsQuery("{ userId: ?0 }")
    boolean existsWithUserId(String userId);

    @Query("{ userId: ?0 }")
    boolean findWithUserId(String userId);
}
```

Comment: Even if this would work it is not a good idea because it would require to block the caller until the mongo query returns which is the opposite of what you usually want to achieve using a ReactiveCrudRepository in a reactive stack.

Answer (score 0):

If the repository can't find the entry, it will return a Mono